# One Promise triggering zero or more Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

#### short question, rather abstract:

Process `A` and process `B` both return promises.

Process `B` needs to call process `A` zero or more times to resolve its promise.  What's the right pattern for this kind of thing?

#### longer, but more concrete, question:

Imagine I have a `produceMsg` process that creates a promise that, when resolved, yields a buffer of n bytes.  (Perhaps it's fetching bytes over a network connection.  And perhaps once in a while it generates an error.)  Here's a test jig that does that:

```
// promise to yield a buffer of up to 20 bytes and an occasional error
function produceMsg() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        if (n === 0) {       // generate an error sometimes...
            reject("some error");
        } else {             // create a buffer with n random bytes
            var msg = createRandomMessage(n);
            console.log('generating', msg);
            resolve(msg);
        }
    });
};

// helper method: create a buffer of n random bytes
function createRandomMessage(n) {
    return Buffer(Array(n).fill().map(function(e) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256); }));
}
```

Now imagine I have a method to `consume` those promises:

```
function consume() {
    setInterval(function() {
        produceMsg()
            .then(function(b)  { console.log("==> fetched", b); })
            .catch(function(b) { console.log("==> error", b); })
                ;
    }, 200);
}
```

Testing it out, it works as expected:

```
generating <Buffer c8 71 6a 3f fe 84 05 71>
==> fetched <Buffer c8 71 6a 3f fe 84 05 71>
generating <Buffer 03 66>
==> fetched <Buffer 03 66>
==> error some error
generating <Buffer 49 d2 4f 6f d6 bc 48 cf e7 db f7 f6 f7 e2 e7 5c df>
==> fetched <Buffer 49 d2 4f 6f d6 bc 48 cf e7 db f7 f6 f7 e2 e7 5c df>
generating <Buffer ef 6c 5f 3c 2f c8 b1 ff b5 eb 13 0e 76 d8>
==> fetched <Buffer ef 6c 5f 3c 2f c8 b1 ff b5 eb 13 0e 76 d8>
```

But now I'm told that I have to reframe the incoming packets in to 10 byte chunks.  (Okay, this is a contrived example, but I do have to reframe the packets.)

So I need an intermediate `reframer` object that creates a promise to return ten byte packets whenever it resolves.  If it doesn't have ten bytes, it needs collect bytes from the `produceMsg` process until it accumulates enough.

My modified `consume` method might look like this:

```
function consume() {
    var reframer = new Reframer(produceMsg);
    setInterval(function() {
        reframer.read()
            .then(function(b)  { console.log("==> fetched", b); })
            .catch(function(b) { console.log("==> error", b); })
                ;
    }, 200);
}
```

... and using the same data as above, I'd expect output to look like this:

```
generating <Buffer c8 71 6a 3f fe 84 05 71>
generating <Buffer 03 66>
=> fetched <Buffer c8 71 6a 3f fe 84 05 71 03 66>
=> error some error
generating <Buffer 49 d2 4f 6f d6 bc 48 cf e7 db f7 f6 f7 e2 e7 5c df>
=> fetched <Buffer 49 d2 4f 6f d6 bc 48 cf e7 db>
generating <Buffer ef 6c 5f 3c 2f c8 b1 ff b5 eb 13 0e 76 d8>
=> fetched <Buffer f7 f6 f7 e2 e7 5c df ef 6c 5f>
=> fetched <Buffer 3c 2f c8 b1 ff b5 eb 13 0e 76>
```

(Notice in the last two lines `reframer` produced two messages without calling on `produceMsg` since it had accumulated enough bytes.)

#### the question: what's the structure of `reframer.read()`?

I haven't figured out how to structure the guts of the `reframer.read()` method.  Is there a good pattern for doing this kind of thing, where one promise conditionally chains calls to zero or more promises?

(Note: I'm *not* asking how to `concat` and `slice` Buffers and whatnot -- I already have the code to do that.  What I'm stuck on is the control flow for the generation and resolution of `Promises`.)

Comment: You are looking for recursion it seems.

Comment: @Bergi well, pseudo-recursion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like this:

```
function Reframer(producer) {
    var buffer;     // for accumulation

    this.read = function() {
        if (buffer.length >= max) {
            frame = first "max" bytes removed from buffer
            return Promise.resolve(frame)
        } else {
            return producer.read().then((read_data) => {
                append read_data to buffer
                return this.read();  // pseudo-recurse
            });
        }
    };
}
```

i.e. if the accumulated buffer already has sufficient bytes in it, remove the desired number of bytes from that buffer, and return a promise that is immediately resolved with those bytes.

Otherwise, ask the producer to send more data, add it to the buffer, and then just recurse to the step above.

If any `.reject` is generated by the producer it *should* just propagate through and cause the `.read` method to reject too.

[ An alternative version of the `else` branch might directly resolve with the new data if it's sufficient to fill the buffer to avoid the need to append the whole of the new data to the buffer only to have it removed again immediately in the next recursive step ]

Comment: Works like a champ.  It hadn't occurred to me that I could `return Promise.resolve()` -- that was the missing piece.  (And yes, the producer's `.reject`s are correctly propagated.)

Comment: Stop the presses!  Unit tests uncovered a problem:  Assume producer has resolved with a packet of 11 bytes.  Each time Reframer calls producer.read(), it will receive the same packet, resulting in repeated data.  Or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: @fearless_fool did you actually delete the 10 bytes from the temporary buffer (the ones that end up in `frame`) ?

Comment: ah, or are you only ever expecting a single promise to be returned by `producer` - in my code above I had a `read` method that produces a _new_ promise each time it's called

Comment: Yah, a conceptual flaw on my part: clearly the `read` method needs to return a new promise on each call (because the general contract of a promise is to evaluate to its resolved value.)  I'll have to think about this more.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Alnitak's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak) answer, and I'm motivated to recast it as a general pattern.  (Anyone else should feel free to improve on this).

If you have a Promise-producing process `B` that needs to call Promise-producing process `A` zero or more times in order to resolve its promise, the general pattern would be:

```
function B(A) {
    if (have_necessary_data()) {
        return Promise.resolve(processed_data());
    } else {
        return A().then(function(incoming_data) { 
            do_something_with(incoming_data);
            return B(A);
         });
    }
};
```

Comment: That's interesting. Trying to understand this pattern better. So what the `B` function in this case correspond to? Is it `Reframer` class from example? And what then consumer's code will look like? ...

Comment: Yes - `B()` corresponds (roughly) to `Reframer` above.  And since `B()` returns a Promise, the consumer's code simply treats the return value like any ordinary promise.  But see my "stop the presses" comment above -- `A()` must return a *new* promise at each call, else this won't work.

Comment: Gotcha, curious to see what would be final solution look like. Kudos on pursuing it.

Comment: The short and obscure answer is: Don't try to create a synchronous "pull" function that returns a value when the solution really needs an asynchronous "push" function that performs a side-effect.  Extra points if you can make sense of what I mean by that!  :)

Comment: Ha ha, I think I get it, but do not attempt ask me to explain:)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to do multiply promise resolution, although you can not resolve it at all, one solution to return several buffers at once would be resolve final promise with array of formatted buffers, and than in consumer go over the array:

```
function Reframer (msg) {
    this.msg = msg
    this.stash = []
}

Reframer.prototype.read = function (){
    return this.msg()
        .then((b) => {
            this.stash.push(b)

            // Do check here for stashed Buffers and apply appropriate logic to
            // slice and dice them if there is something to return do this with promise
            // Assuming I have define `chunk` variable which is array of 10 bytes Buffer(s)
            // And if there is anything else left it has to be stashed appropriately for future reuse if any.

            var chunk = [Buffer(10), Buffer(10)]

            return Promise.resolve(chunk)
        })
        .catch((err) => Promise.reject(err))
}
```

And consumer:

```
function consume() {
    var reframer = new Reframer(produceMsg);
    setInterval(function() {
        reframer.read()
            .then(function(abs)  { abs.forEach((b) => console.log("==> fetched", b)); })
            .catch(function(err) { console.log("==> error", err); });
    }, 200);
}
```

Also 'hard' setInterval may create some sort of race conditions. The better pattern IMHO would be recursively called function with setTimeout.

```
var reframerOne = new Reframer(produceMsg);
function consumeOne() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        reframerOne.read()
            .then(function(abs)  { 
                abs.forEach((b) => console.log("==> fetched", b));
                consumeOne();
            })
            .catch(function(err) { console.log("==> error", err); });
    }, 200);
}
```

Though you may put it just for example here. So just clarifying in this case.

Comment: Dmi3y: I haven't verified it, but I think there's a problem w your solution: imagine the producer yields 40 bites each time. But reframer blocks until producer generates a message, and then it can only yield one packet of 10 bytes, so it will fall further and further behind.  I think Alnitak's response has promise.

Comment: Well if producer yields 40 bites a time than reframer's promise going to be resolved with array of 4 chanked buffers at once... and left stash empty for the next call

Comment: Ah - I get it.  Thanks for the clarification.